# Batch File - Add Extension to Strings in a .txt File

Tags: string, batch-file

I am trying to get this batch file to work but not sure exactlty what to do from here...
What I need is to have a batch file add extensions to multiple text strings that have special characters in half of them, then output to new txt file.
With this batch the way it is now, it will add the extension to the strings in the text file, and also output the new txt file, but will pass on the one's that have special characters.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set addtext=.jpg 
for /f "delims=*" %%a in (list.txt) do (echo/|set /p =%%a%addtext% & echo\) 
>>new_list.txt
```

Any Help is Over Appreciated! 
THANKS...

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
for /f "delims=*" %%a in (list.txt) do (echo(%%a%addtext%)>>new_list.txt
```

Do what you want?

Without examples of what's on your input file and what you require on the output, we have to analyse the code for what's in your head - and remember, what's in your code doesn't do what's in youir head. If it did, you wouldn't be asking your question.

Comment: The output txt file is basically a bunch of simple 1 -3 word filenames without extension that I need to add extensions to.  alot of them contain special characters as these * " ‘ . ! - ()     I do know you bat works good but the main and only thing I see wrong with the output is the wildcard star file names are being trimmed down to the Star.

Comment: Would have been easier to provide some examples rather than construct all that. Now what happens if tyou remove the asterisk, so that `"delims="` ?

Comment: Thank You for the suggestions, I believed it worked now removing the asterisk.  one thing though, it deleted 1 string completely in the output file.  Out of 780 strings, and the correlating files its gonna be fun trying to narrow that one down.  But I am completely 100% satisfied.  Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Not at all. Just create a new file using the same instruction, but don't add the `%addtext%`. Then `fc list.txt newestfile.txt` which should reveal the culprit.

Comment: Once again thanks so much!  But unfortunatly, file compare is not able to find it, which leads me to believe I should back track my work.  I have a feeling this is my mistake and your suggestion was not the Issue.

Comment: i wen't back and revisited this code but for some strange reason,  it now leaves spaces before the extensions.